# Obtrusive notifications

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-note-4

If I'm playing a game or watching something in full screen, why does the notifications come over it? I've noticed especially whatsapp notifications fill up the screen.

I need to be able to only stop the heads up notifications when in game mode or full screen watching video, not totally turn it off. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Need some clarification: are you running on Lollipop? If it's, then it's the heads-up notification (new feature on Lollipop), if it's not, and only WhatsApp do that, then check the settings on your WhatsApp.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes it's loliipop.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first question: Because Google wanted a new notification system that was more visible and obvious, much the way iOS handles their notifications. A lot of defectors from iOS actually missed that.

Answer to second question: this is done on a per-app basis, for those that support it. Most apps don't even use the feature, but for those that do, some allow you to disable the pop-ups, or heads up notifications. But that's the only real way to do so without potentially disabling notifications in general.

Answer (score 0):

Open Whatsapp and set the following for **Message Notification** and **Group Notifications**

> Whatsapp-> Settings -> Notifications -> Popup Notifications -> None

Now you won't get the notification poped up when you are using some other applications. And all the popup nofications for individual and group notifications will be turned off.